# What's the proper reading order for the manga in the Steins;Gate series?

Tags: steins-gate

I ended up reading Steins;Gate, but after I had finished it, I wasn't sure which one I should read next. When searching for Steins;Gate cartoons, I found all these different parts and I started reading Bokan no Rellion and it looks like it's the same story, but from a different character's perspective. So what about the other parts? Are they the same story too or are they sequels and is there a specific order I should use to get the most out of the story?

- Steins;Gate
- Steins;Gate: Bōkan no Rebellion
- Steins;Gate: Onshu no Braunian Motion
- Steins;Gate: Shijō Saikyō no Slight Fever
- Steins;Gate: Hiyoku Renri no Sweets Honey
- Steins;Gate: Aishin Meizu no Babel
- Steins;Gate!

Comment: Good question; I've been wondering, myself. There's also "Hen'i Kuukan no Octet", "Hiyoku Renri no Future Honey", "Hoshikuzu no Droplet", and "Mugen Enten no Arc Light". And then there's all the novel spinoffs, too...

Comment: By "reading Steins;Gate" do you mean a Light Novel of the Visual Novel?

Comment: @Memor-X With "reading" I meant the comics. If the novels are translated into English, I might consider reading them too, although it isn't quite sure in what they should be read.

Comment: * in what order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you read them in order of publication date, you should be fine.
All of the manga to date (excluding the multi-artist anthologies), listed in order of publication date:

『STEINS; GATE』11/2010~9/2013 (the main storyline)

[『STEINS;GATE 亡環のリベリオン』](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Rebellion_of_the_Missing_Ring)(*Rebellion of the Missing Ring*) 2/2010~9/2011 (side story, focused on Suzuha in the 0.000000, 0.337187, and 0.409431% World Lines)

[『STEINS;GATE 史上最強のスライトフィーバー』](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/History%27s_Strongest_Slight_Fever) (*The World's Strongest Slight Fever*) 2/2011~10/2011 (the main storyline, focused on Kurisu)

『しゅたいんず・げーと!』(*Steins・Gate!*) 3/2011~5/2012 (parody of the main storyline)

『STEINS;GATE DROPS』8/2011~3/2012 (a 4-panel gag comic, the storyline of the comedic Xbox360 fandisc game『STEINS;GATE 比翼恋理のだーりん』[*Loving Vows' Darling*], set in the 3% World Line)

『STEINS;GATE 星屑のデュプレット』(*Stardust Duplet*) 8/2011~3/2012 (the storyline of the fandisc, focused on Mayuri)

[『STEINS;GATE 比翼恋理のスイーツはにー』](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Steins;Gate_-_Darling_of_Loving_Vows) (*Loving Vows’ Sweets Honey*) 10/2011~3/2012 (the storyline of the fandisc, focused on Kurisu)

[『STEINS;GATE 恩讐のブラウニアンモーション』](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Braunian_Motion_of_Love_and_Hate)(*Braunian Motion of Love and Hate*) 4/2012~7/2012 (side story, focused on the past of Mr. Braun)

『STEINS;GATE 比翼恋理のフューチャーはにー』(*Loving Vows’ Future Honey*) 5/2012~? (the storyline of the fandisc, focused on Suzuha)

『STEINS;GATE もっと比翼恋理のスイーツはにー』(*Even More Loving Vows’ Sweets Honey*) 6/2012~12/2012 (spin-off from the storyline of the fandisc, about Lab Members going to school)

『STEINS;GATE 変移空間のオクテット』(*Variant Space Octet*) 6/2012~1/2013 (the storyline of the game of the same name, which is a non-canon crossover with *Chaos;Head*)

『STEINS;GATE 比翼恋理の+ニャン2 くらいしす☆』(*Loving Vows + Meow2 Crisis*) 6/2012~1/2013 (the storyline of the fandisc, focused on Feris)

『STEINS;GATE -哀心迷図のバベル-』(*Babel of the Grieved Maze*) 6/2012~2/2014 (the storyline of the CD drama[『STEINS;GATEドラマCDα「哀心迷図のバベル」ダイバージェンス0.571046%』](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=305040), which is the main storyline focused on Kurisu)

『STEINS;GATE 比翼恋理のスイーツはにーふぁいなる』(*Loving Vows’ Sweets Honey Final*) 1/2013~6/2013 (sequel to the fandisc storyline manga)

[『STEINS;GATE 閉時曲線のエピグラフ』](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Epigraph_of_the_Closed_Curve)(*Epigraph of the Closed Curve*) 2/2013~12/2013 (side story, the storyline of the light novel  of the same name, set in winter 2010 in the Beta Attractor Field around the 1.129848 and 1.130205% World Lines)

『劇場版STEINS;GATE 負荷領域のデジャヴ』(*Loading Area of Déjà Vu*) 5/2013~12/2013 (the storyline of the movie of the same name, set one year after the events of the TV series)

『STEINS;GATE -無限遠点のアークライト-』(*Arc Light of the Point of Infinity*) 3/2014~present (the storyline of the CD drama 『STEINS;GATEドラマCDβ「無限遠点のアークライト」ダイバージェンス1.130205%』, focused on Mayuri)

『STEINS;GATE 永劫回帰のパンドラ』(*Pandora of Eternal Recurrence*) 5/2014~present (side story, continuation of *Epigraph of the Closed Curve*, set in the Beta Attractor Field in 2010)

Comment: Could you add where you found this list?

Comment: @Peter Raeves, I'm sorry I didn't see your comment until now. Some of this list comes from the Japanese Wikipedia pages and the Steins;Gate Wiki but I compiled it myself from a fair number of Japanese and English-language websites since I didn't find a singular comprehensive list (it took me well over an hour)

Answer (score 2):

I've only watched the anime so I can't 100% confirm, but:

Wikipedia says all of those mangas are side-stories. Most of them are the story from a certain character's point of view, and I believe one is material from a fandisc. Steins;Gate! is a spinoff comedy.

So pretty much, whatever order you feel like.